# I m having Issue with xCode7.3 debugging

Tags: xcode

I am trying to debug application but instead of a class variable and breakpoints. I am getting the register and memory location.

Whereas the breakpoints are set in the class and I am trying to figure out how to get this resolve.

**Register and Memory Location:**

[image]

Comment: Did you Add All Exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix that by reseting Xcode's preferences.

Run this command in your terminal:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```